# Best Language/Tool To Develop GUI on Windows

Tags: windows, user-interface, new-operator

I reviewed the answers provided to the "GUI Programming APIs" post and wondering if these answers still apply.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610/gui-programming-apis

Specifically from that thread it appears that QT is the one that was most referenced with wxWidgets and Shoes a close second and third.

I just wanted to make sure that a definitive winner has not emerged in the past 6 months since that question was posted.

I am constrained to target OpenSource and Freeware solutions, so I will strongly lean that way.

Thanks for any feedback and insights.  I've got a little experience with Perl, C++, and VB.

Comment: +1 on Qt. see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115045/good-c-gui-library-for-windows) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366043/what-are-some-of-the-best-cross-platform-c-ui-toolkits-today)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QT is still one of if not the most popular open source GUI programming API right now because it can target all the major platforms (Linux, OS X, and Windows). I don't think the results of that question have changed much if at all in the last 6 months.

Comment: Thanks a ton for all the response.  Unfortunately, only one answer can be accepted, so it appears that QT is still in the lead.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

.NET via Mono (mono-project.com)